# Can I have different domains for each store within one website

Tags: multistore

Using Magento's terminology of Website & Store, can I create 2 stores within a single website and use different top level domain names for each store?

Or must I use separate websites if I want to use different domains?

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 separate domains for 2 store views under the same website.
But you have to be careful to set `Use SID on Frontend` from System->Configuration->Web->Session Validation Settings to `Yes`. You don't want your customers losing session just for changing the language.